# Magento Custom Module How to store variable in config.xml

Tags: php, configuration, magento, module

I have a custom module that is working just fine but I would like to be able to store variables in the config so I can use them in my code. (For example a default error message)

I think I can access them by using Mage::getStoreConfig('/some/path/here'); but I don't know how to add them to the modules config.xml (myname/mymodule/etc/config.xml) so that I can use them in my code?

Anyone have a clue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading [these](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration) two [articles](http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_configuration_in_depth_tutorial) should give you the information you need to add your own custom configuration variable, which will automatically give you a UI to enter values in the Admin.

If you want to set a default value for your new configuration variables, there's a top level `config.xml` node named `default` which will let you do that.  Consider the following

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <default>
        <web>
            <default>
                <cms_home_page>home</cms_home_page>
                <cms_no_route>no-route</cms_no_route>
                <cms_no_cookies>enable-cookies</cms_no_cookies>
                <front>cms</front>
                <no_route>cms/index/noRoute</no_route>
                <show_cms_breadcrumbs>1</show_cms_breadcrumbs>
            </default>
        </web>
        <cms>
            <wysiwyg>
                <enabled>enabled</enabled>
            </wysiwyg>
        </cms>
    </default>
    <!-- ... -->
</config>
```

This structure in `config.xml` sets default values for the following config variables

```
web/default/cms_home_page
web/default/cms_no_route
web/default/cms_no_cookies
web/default/front
web/default/no_route
web/default/show_cms_breadcrumbs

cms/wysiwyg/enabled
```

Comment: Alan, that's exactly what I needed. Using the default node was what I was looking for. Many thanks!